# howto make a simple selection in haskell?

Tags: haskell

i have a problem, this code dont work and i dont know why:

```
foo :: [String] -> IO [String]
foo input = do
    choice <- getLine
    if choice == "1" then do
        putStrLn "good choice"
        return input
    else
        return []
```

Comment: What do you mean by "this code dont work".. any compiler error ? runtime error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is (with a bit of retabbing) the code works for me.  if/else is difficult to get correct with the tabs.  The Wiki article [if/then/else](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/If-then-else) should help.

```
foo :: [String] -> IO [String]
foo input = do
  choice <- getLine
  if choice == "1" then do
    putStrLn "good choice"
    return input
    else
    return []
```

Eliminating the inner `do` expression makes the if/then block a little more easy to indent.

```
foo2 input = do
  choice <- getLine
  if (choice == "1") 
  then (putStrLn "good choice" >> return input)
  else (return [])
```